# Decking on a Metal Roof

Tags: roof, deck, building-regulations, decking, metal-roof

I can't say for sure that I've ever seen a deck on a metal roof... is it against code? If not, can anyone point me in the right direction for information about building a deck (or a crows nest) on top of a house with a **metal** roof? Tips, cons, and codes are also of interest.

[image]

Comment: I don't see why it would be any different you will still need to anchor the support's to the trusses. If your trusses can handle the weight would be the big question.

Comment: Yeah... but the corrugation and battens (or space between the roof and truss) needs to be accounted for. Maybe the easiest way is to cut a hole through the roof? But I've had difficulty keeping water out of vents and skylights with flashing. The way I have found to deal with leaks on metal roofs it is to mix vermiculite with aluminum paint and build a solid boot-like water shedding structure around the leaking edges/areas. Anything less seems to be temporary. Rubber boots get hot and swell and basically wrinkle up, causing gaps, silicone separates, tar flows, butyl tape (psht), etc.